# Import Python Classes and Function between folder on same direcetory level

Tags: python, import

Using this structure:

```
Root
├─ __init__.py
└─ Core
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ Game
    │  ├─ game.py
    │  └─ __init__.py
    └─ Player
        ├─ player.py
        └─ __init__.py
```

The folder `Core` has two folders called `Game` and `Player`. In the `player.py` file a function called `drink()` prints a text.
When trying to call the `drink` function in the `game.py` file, the error `ModuleNotFoundError` is thrown.

```
from Core.Player.player import drink

drink()
```

In theory, this should work, and by using the `__init__.py` files, python should recognize, that it is a module. This question has been asked in a similar way many times, and there is still not an answer that satisfies this request. At least not in this way. Adding paths or environmental variables is not an option.

As a reference, this is the XRP Python framework, which uses a nice-looking way of importing functions, but it does not work in my case: https://github.com/XRPLF/xrpl-py/tree/master/xrpl
[image]

Comment: if you are trying to run the game.py file directly no it won't work.  Your apps entry point should be in the top level of your package.  game.py is the bottom.

Comment: @mkrieger1, why is that still not allowed? It definitely exists in other languages and as far as I can tell: here they also import from the other folders: https://github.com/algorand/pyteal/blob/master/pyteal/ir/tealblock.py

Comment: Okay, then this was a misunderstanding, I am sorry. But do you have an idea, on why this does not work in this case? In theory this should work like in the XRP or Algorand case

Comment: If `Root` is a package, then `Core` is not a top-level package, but a module/subpackage contained in `Root`. `Root` should *not* be a package, but a directory to add to your module search path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved for me personally with the setup of a correct launch.json.
The launch.json should look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The location of the launch.json has to be in your .vscode folder:

```
your_project/
│
├── .vscode/
│   ├── launch.json
│
└── (other project files and folders)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the Player subdir to your sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Root/Core/Player')

...

from Player import drink

drink()
```